# Specifying the path for PostgreSQL in jboss

Tags: postgresql, jboss, datasource

I am using PostgreSQL in jboss as the database. But the maximum information I am giving jboss about PostgreSQL  on my system is

```
<jndi-name>PostgresDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
```

How does JBoss know where postgresql is located in the system? Any where I have not specified the path information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify a "path" to connect to a database server.

In your configuration you told JBoss that that PostgreSQL is running on the same machine as JBoss (localhost) and that it's accepting connections through port 5432.

JBoss does not need to know where PostgreSQL "is located". They will talk through a TCP connection to each other.

Not knowing where the data is phyiscally stored is one of the purposes of having a database *server*.

Comment: okay.. But what is jndi name. What is the following in standardjbosscmp.xml - <datasource>java:/PostgresDS</datasource>
   <datasource-mapping>postgresq</datasource-mapping>

Comment: The JNDI name is, well, the JNDI name. It's a way to identify resources in a JavaEE environment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi/index.html  this is also covered in the JavaEE tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjh.html